# LBBlurredImage NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm using the following library:

https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage

This is the code I'm using to blur my background image that I'm adding to a ViewController:

```
var background = UIImage(named: "bg")
var backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: background)
backgroundImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill;
backgroundImageView.setImageToBlur(background, blurRadius: 10, completionBlock: { () -> Void in
    println("The blurred image has been set")
})
self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
```

I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure why:

```
-[UIImageView setImageToBlur:blurRadius:completionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff08a802390
2015-01-27 10:50:44.326 TestApp[9289:66346] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageToBlur:blurRadius:completionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff08a802390'
```

**UPDATE:**

Looks like I'm not the only one to receive [the error](https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage/issues/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception was that the image I was passing was `nil` and in turn it was violating `NSParameterAssert(image);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var background = UIImage(named: "bg")
```

Instead of this try to specify the full path of the image.
It worked for me and I am pretty sure it will work for you too.

You can also try this path with your code

```
var background = UIImage(named: "Images/bg");
```

Comment: No need to specify the full path of the image until you are using any other source for your image.